# Is there any methods to measure running period of a program?

Tags: matlab, runtime

I made two programs for simulating a specific system; One is mine, the other is a reproduction according to a journal (not mine).

I first ran

```
clc;close all;clear all;
tic
for run=1:10000
    result1{run} = runCode1;
end
Time = toc;
result1{10001} = toc/10000;
save('Mine', 'result1');
```

and then, I ran

```
clc;close all;clear all;
tic
for run=1:10000
    result2{run} = runMyCode2;
end
Time = toc;
result2{10001} = toc/10000;
save('Others', 'result2');
```

I compared two parameters "result1{10001}" and "result2{10001}".
However, I am worried a something due to the fact that the tic/toc represents real time.

I have to run two codes under equal conditions, but now I'm running the two codes sequentially.
Also, the codes spend around 20 hours and 50 hours, respectively.
Hence, I have to run around 70 hours!!! I cannot bear not to use the computer for 70 hours. I have to do another things a lot. BUT, If I run somethings, e.g., IEs, chromes, latex, messengers, ppt, printing, etc., they may affect the codes' running time.

### How can I do an equivalent-conditional-comparison between two codes?

---

I will add some contents in detail.

```
clc;close all;clear all;
Data = load('RawData');
for monte=1:100
    nextState = Initialize(Data, ...);
    for timeIdx = 1:1000
        currState = EvaluateCurrentState(nextState, Data{timeIdx});
        out{monte,timeIdx} = EvaluatePerformance(currState);
        nextState = updateState(currState); % using the currState, subalgorithms are run.
    end
end
```

And then, I deal with this 100 by 1000 cell data; find mean, moving mean, plotting, and so on.

Comment: Why run it 10 thousand times? If you do 100 times it will be 12 minutes only. If you do 10 runs it will be a bit over a minute. Is there a reason you need 10000 repetitions? Also, look for the function `timeit`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It is stochastic-based code. So, I run many times, and then I determine a result as the expected value, i.e., Monte Carlo simulation. That's why I ran 100 times. Also, each time, I test over 100 time steps, so around 10000 iteration is needed. The above code is a sample code for me to express my situation well.

Comment: What is the variance of the `result1` and `result2` arrays? Does execution time really vary a lot? Stochastic simulations do not need to have stochastic running times...

Comment: @CrisLuengo According to the condition, the algorithm takes different stochastic-subalgorithms, and by the results of the selected subalgorithm, stochastically update the conditions. Here, the subalgorithms have very different running times. For example, one is just finding gradient, but the other contains huge processes.

Comment: So running time is determined by a Poisson distribution? If you can determine that distribution, you can compute how many repetitions you need to demonstrate a difference in the means with a given confidence. It seems to me that the 10000 repetitions is rather arbitrary, and the difference between 20 hours and 50 hours is gigantic. You probably need a lot fewer repetitions to demonstrate your algorithm is faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your statistics with N=5 and keep time per run, than from variance you can decide if you need more runs. anyway 10000 is probably too much.

```
clc;close all;clear all;

N=5;
result1=cell(1,N+2);
tocs1=zeros(1,N);
for run=1:N
    starttime=tic;
    result1{run} = runCode1;
    tocs1(run)=toc(starttime);
end
result1{N+1} = mean(tocs1);
result1{N+2} = std(tocs1);
save('Mine', 'result1','tocs1');
```

Comment: I added my question. I have time-series data over 1000 time steps.